# expand one file in second file

Tags: powershell, match, expand

I have two folders in which .txt files are kept.

```
Folder1 has File1.txt
Folder2 has File2.txt
```

Contents of `File1.txt`

```
Some text
    ABCD123X Execute String1
Some text
```

Contents of `File2.txt`

```
String1 Procedure
ABCD
EFGH
```

Output :

```
Some text
    ABCD123X Execute String1

    ABCD
    EFGH

Some text
```

Requirement :

I want to expand `'Execute String1'` in File1.txt itself if I find  pattern `'String1 Procedure'` in File2.txt

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$string1 = $null
gc $file.fullname | ? {
  if ($_ -match "(.*)EXECUTE(\s)([A-Za-z_0-9][^ |^,]*)" -and $_ -notmatch "^\/\/*") {
    $string1 = $matches[3]
  } elseif ($string1 -ne $null) {
    get-content file.fullname, $string1.fullname | out-file $combined.txt
    # This is appending string1.txt file at end of file.txt
  } 
}
```

I need a way that the string1.txt gets appended into file.txt NOT at end but at position just below where I find. Like this :

```
Some text
ABCD123X Execute String1
ABCD
EFGH
Some text
```

Comment: Does `File1.txt` contain only this single string, or are there several replacement strings in it?

Comment: File1.txt contain other strings as well and Thanks for editing the question for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `File1.txt` contains a list of replacement strings (I'm going to assume that each line ends with the identifier word), I'd suggest to read them into a hashtable like this:

```
$replacements = @{};
Get-Content "C:\path\to\File1.txt" | ? { $_ -match '.* (\S+)$' } | % {
  $replacements[$matches[1]] = $matches[0]
}
```

The [`-match` operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) matches a string against a [regular expression](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/archive/2012/03/20/chapter-13-text-and-regular-expressions.aspx):

```
"string" -match 'expression'
```

The resulting matches are automatically stored in a hashtable `$matches`. Example:

```
PS C:\> "ABCD123X Execute String1" -match '.* (\S+)$'
True
PS C:\> $matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
1                              String1
0                              ABCD123X Execute String1
```

With that, you take the the whole match (`$matches[0]`) and put it into the hashtable `$replacements` using the first submatch (the part between the parentheses in the regular expression, `$matches[1]`) as the key for this value:

```
$replacements[$matches[1]] = $matches[0]
       ^          ^              ^
   hashtable     key           value
```

A hashtable is basically a dictionary where you can look up phrases by keyword. Example:

```
PS C:\> $phonebook = @{
>> "Amy" = "555-1234";
>> "Eve" = "555-6666";
>> "Ivy" = "555-4223";
>> }
>>
PS C:\> $phonebook

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Amy                            555-1234
Eve                            555-6666
Ivy                            555-4223

PS C:\> $phonebook["Mia"] = "555-1327"
PS C:\> $phonebook

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Amy                            555-1234
Eve                            555-6666
Ivy                            555-4223
Mia                            555-1327

PS C:\> "Amy's number is: " + $phonebook["amy"]
Amy's number is: 555-1234
```

In your case the dictionary contains the identifier words ("String1" et al.) as keys and the whole phrase ("ABCD123X Execute String1") as the value associated with the key.

With this hashtable you can then do the replacements in `File2.txt` like this:

```
if { $_ -match '^(\S+) procedure' } {
  # print the phrase from the $replacements hashtable if a matching line is found
  $replacements[$matches[1]]
} else {
  # otherwise print the original line
  $_
}
```

The rest you'll have to figure out yourself, since this is your homework, not mine.